# Proper method to measure time spent on a Fragment in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am integrating analytics into my app and I am having a slight issue. I want to measure the visible time of a Fragment linked to Navigation Drawer.

I do something like this:

```
long startTime, endTime;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    MixpanelUtils.trackScreenTime(mixpanel, SCREEN, startTime, endTime);
}
```

This method works fine when the fragments are used in a ViewPager, but the behaviour is erratic in case of Navigation Drawer fragments. What would be the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: I think the time interval between `OnResume` and `OnPause` would be the most accurate

Comment: somehow `onResume` is not being called correctly for me. Isn't there any other method?

Comment: there is `onViewStateRestored`